# C# Load Dialog Box (Unable to Load, but when it does, its actions do not function)

Tags: c#, user-interface

I am using C# and I have a Load button in my GUI program that is not prompting the user with a warning to save data before loading a new one. How can I make it so that the prompt message can be displayed properly? Data loads correctly as I want, but the dialog message is not being displayed.

This is part of my code:

```
private bool dirtyText;
private bool dirtyFilename;

#region load


//================================
 //       LOAD     
 //================================

private void loadFile()
{
    try
    {
        textBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(fileName.Text);
        dirtyText = false;
        dirtyFileName = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Load failed: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

 //================================
 //       LOAD     - actual code to load files
 //================================

private void load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dirtyFileName)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Your data have not been saved yet. Would you like to save them before loading?", "Unchanged data", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

        switch (result)
        {
            case DialogResult.Yes:
                File.WriteAllText(fileName.Text, " ");
                loadFile();
                break;
            case DialogResult.No:
                loadFile();
                break;
            case DialogResult.Cancel:
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        loadFile();
    }
}

#endregion
```

The picture below shows you what I'd like to see when I click on Load.

[image]

Also a quick note: I did made the dialog box work however, by removing the entire block of code that includes the switch statement from the if statement and getting rid of the if-else statement; but doing this renders all the buttons of the dialog box impotent. The save don't save the file, the load erases the text and the cancel, well... the cancel just does what it does best: canceling the action. Technically the important buttons are useless.

I hope I get a solution to this. Appreciate it.

Comment: your condition in `load_Click` is wrong please use `if (!dirtyFileName)` instead of `if (dirtyFileName)`

Comment: In the code you've shown, `dirtyFileName` is always `false`, so the `DialogResult` code will never execute

Comment: I assigned a bool value to my dirtyFileName and also my dirtyText while I'm at it and it worked. Thank you guys! I appreciate it! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply remove the check for the `dirtyFileName` (it's always false in your example) it should work:

```
private void load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Your data have not been saved yet. Would you like to save them before loading?", "Unchanged data", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

     switch (result)
     {
        case DialogResult.Yes:
            File.WriteAllText(fileName.Text, " ");
            loadFile();
            break;
        case DialogResult.No:
            loadFile();
            break;
        case DialogResult.Cancel:
            break;
    }
}
```

However it'd be a better idea to overthink why you never assign `dirtyFileName`, as the prompt is shown alwyays now.

Comment: I assigned a bool value to my dirtyFileName and also my dirtyText while I'm at it and it worked. Thank you guys! I appreciate it! :D